# Jquery scroll listener isn't working, could you tell me what the issue is?

Tags: javascript, jquery

All I'm attempting to do right now is get the scroll position, and it isn't working for some reason.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#showScroll").html("Scroll = " + "Testing Text");
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#showScroll").html("Scroll = " + $(this).scroll() + " : " + $(this).scrollTop());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <div>
    <p id="showScroll">Scroll is: </p>
  </div>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
</div>
```

I have also tried placing the scroll listener on document, this, and divs to no avail.

Comment: The `scroll` event has `bubbles: false`, which means you need to listen to the event on exactly the DOM element where it occurs.

Comment: New to jQuery, could you elaborate on this?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: That has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: The other reason your code won't work is that inside your scroll event handler, you're triggering a new scroll event (`$(this).scroll()`), which in turn will make the event handler run again, which will again trigger a scroll event, which...

Comment: Okay, if I remove that, it sets the value to 0, and doesn't change.  That's progress, any idea why the value isn't updating?

Comment: Instead of `$(this).scrollTop()` you can try `window.scrollTop`. I've stopped using jQuery long ago, so I cannot really help you with that. The native DOM API to me feels so much more adequate.

Comment: Does CSS interfere with this by any chance?  i notice sometimes it will work, and most of the time it will not.

Comment: Tried this:  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  document.getElementById('showScroll').innerHTML = pageYOffset + 'px';
}); too and it has the sometimes effect as well, but most of the time it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to understand what it means when a native event by default won't bubble. It means that listeners registered on ancestor elements of the element where the scroll occurs **will never trigger.**

Comment: It should be $("#showScroll").html("Scroll = " + $(document).innerHeight() + " : " + $(document).scrollTop());

Comment: So, if I were to wrap the entire page in a div, let's say ,<div id="contentDiv"> and set the listener to that div, would it all register then?  Or what are my options here?

Comment: Though, considering the scroll could be on top of child elements, would the event still not trigger?  Or am I way off base?

Comment: You register the listener on the element which you expect the scroll event to occur on. As simple as that. For that to be a `div` (or other element) the CSS would have to a) limit its `height` or `max-height`, and b) make the element `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: scroll;` (resp. `overflow-y: auto;` or `overflow-y: scroll;`).

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$(this).scroll()`. You only need `.scrollTop()` to retrieve the scroll offset.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#showScroll").html("Scroll = " + "Testing Text");
  jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#showScroll").html("Scroll = " + $(this).scrollTop());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <div>
    <p id="showScroll">Scroll is: </p>
  </div>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
  <p>random Text</p>
</div>
```